# PHP's scandir with ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, scandir

I have some content loaded via ajax that includes the `scandir()` function.  On local and on my server it works perfectly, however on my client's server it didn't work because they run PHP4 (scandir() was implemented in version 5).  I called tech support and their solution was to change file extensions from .php to .php5.  However, this only partially works if I call directly the page, but when I load it via ajax it does not.

Is there a way to fix this?  I didn't know ajax and PHP could be incompatible.

EDIT

Here's part of the code.  Is simply an image gallery and I'm using `scandir()` to get the images:

```
<div id="#vtabs-content-a">
    <ul class="slider">
        <?php
            $featured_dir = 'img/systems/6020/';
            $scan = scandir($featured_dir);
            echo '<li id="' . $scan[2] . '"><img src="' . $featured_dir . $scan[2] . '" alt="' . $scan[2] . '" width="700" height="350" /></li>';
        ?>
    </ul>
    <ul class="thumb 6020a">
        <?php
            $dir = 'img/systems/6020/z_thumbs/';
            $scan = scandir($dir);  
            for ($i = 0; $i<count($scan); $i++) {
                if ($scan[$i] != '.' && $scan[$i] != '..') {
                echo '<li><a href="#' . $featured_dir . $scan[$i] . '"><img src="' . $dir . $scan[$i] . '" alt="' . $scan[$i] . '" width="40" height="40" /></a></li>';
                }
            }; 
        ?>
    </ul>
```

I actually had forgotten to change to .php5 in the ajax call, already did it but still won't work.  Another point is that when I call the page directly the slideshow doesn't work, but at least the pictures are there.

The ajax call is this:

```
$(".a6020").live("click", function(){
    $("#main").load("a6020.php5 #container", function(){
        $('#vtabs5').jVertTabs();
        $.getScript("js/scandir.js", function(){
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You will need to show some code. What happens if you make the Ajax call directly in your browser? What return values do you get?

Comment: I suppose that in your ajax request you havent replaced .php with .php5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding a .htaccess file to run php5 on extensions that end in .php by adding

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

To a .htaccess file.